# how to deploy pytorch based GAN model to android

Tags: deployment, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I have trained and tested the pytorch based GAN model and now I want to deploy it to Android.
I have read about converting cnn model to onnx format and then to cafe2
but I don't know how to use it if there is more than one model i.e. generator, discriminator, encoder-decoder models.

Comment: Hi sam, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions here are expected to show research effort, that is, what you've already done to solve your problem. We're happy to help, but only after you've tried yourself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!